# Android twitter login integration with fabric, getting a white screen on click then it closes the white screen

Tags: java, android, api, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to setup twitter login in android studio with fabric. Everything builds nicely without any errors.

When I try running the application on my phone and press the twitter login button, it goes to a white screen and shows a progress bar and then it closes and goes back to the screen with the twitter button. It doesn't crash the app, it only gives me an error.

I've followed twitters developer documentation perfectly.
This is the error i'm getting

```
01-25 16:58:59.359 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: SSO auth activity not found
01-25 16:58:59.369 827-1358/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig
01-25 16:58:59.369 827-1358/? E/Parcel: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig
01-25 16:58:59.369 827-1358/? E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/sdk/android/core/TwitterAuthConfig
01-25 16:58:59.369 827-1358/? E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-25 16:59:00.399 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
01-25 16:59:00.399 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: <hash>
01-25 16:59:00.399 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:   <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
01-25 16:59:00.399 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:   <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
01-25 16:59:00.399 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: </hash>
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:388)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
01-25 16:59:00.419 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-25 16:59:00.799 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 E/Twitter:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit: Login with Twitter failure
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-25 16:59:00.829 32491-32491/com.myegotest.ego_17012016 D/TwitterKit:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my activity code

```
package com.myegotest.ego_17012016;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Arrays;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class SocialNetworkSelector_setupPage2 extends Activity {

    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "key here";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "key here";
    private TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_network_selector_setup_page2);


        twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);



        twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterSession session = result.data;

                String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myegotest.ego_17012016">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.myegotest.com" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AccountConfirmationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_account_confirmation"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ResetPassword"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LetGetStarted_setupPage4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_let_get_started"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".UploadPhoto_setupPage3" >
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ImageListView" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ViewFullImage" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SocialNetworkSelector_setupPage2" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="key here" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myegotest.ego_17012016"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a callback URL in [the Twitter App Settings](https://apps.twitter.com/). It actually doesn't matter what you set it to, it will be replaced automatically.

Comment: Also, you need to ignore the `It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url` advice and **NOT** tick the **Enable Callback Locking** checkbox... :-/